# android one button share another java use

Tags: android, button, bluetooth

If I want to design a button that all java can use it without need to write it in every java,
what should I do?

For Example:
I design a Button.OnClickListener function to search bluetooth devices.
but another java also need to use this Button.OnClickListener function,
I don't want to write same way on two java.

ledWrite.xml:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btnScan" />
<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/tBtnWrite" />
```

bluetoothUtils.java

```
// Intent request codes
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;

private Button button_scan;
button_scan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
button_scan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View v) {
        scanbt(); 
  }
});

private void scanbt(){
   Intent serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
   startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE); 
}
```

then I design LedWrite.java:

```
private ToggleButton digitalOutBtn; //LED On/OFF
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.ledwrite);

digitalOutBtn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tBtnWrite);
digitalOutBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
public void onClick(View v){
  if(digitalOutBtn.isChecked()){ //sendMessage("D1"); }
   else{sendMessage("D0";}
}
```

How can I use button_scan in LedWrite.java?

Comment: create a class that implements onclicklistener and use it in all of your buttons

Comment: lets assume you created a class name customOnClick that implements OnClickListener. You can use it like this: Button.setOnClickListener(new CustomOnClick());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call a method defined is some other Activity on press of a button, then you can make that method as static.

Let's assume that you have a method named `searchBluetooth()` in `MainActvity` and you want to call it from `SecondActivity`.

Define `searchBluetooth()` in `MainActvity` like,

`public static void searchBluetooth()`

Call this method from `SecondActivity` like,

`MainActivity.searchBluetooth()`

If you don't want to use static because of memory consumption then try with inheritance.

Create a class `CommonActivity` which extends Activity class

```
class CommonActivity extends Activity
{

  // here define your searchBluetooth method

  public void searchBluetooth()
  {

      // your code here
  }

}


If you want to make use of it in Second Activity then 


class SecondActivity extends CommonActivity
{

    // here you can access `searchBluetooth()` method

}
```

Answer (score 0):

enclosure a BluetoothListener class?

```
public BluetoothListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        do something you want...
    }
}
```

then invoke the class in two different class, eg,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new BluetoothListener());
```

I recently started learning android and this answer may have some error, if so, please let me know, Thanks.